Revert Cursor Line Higlighting on Leaving Insert Mode
Apologies in advance if this is a RTFM case, but I have checked pretty thoroughly and I am still stumped. I am running Vim with the afterglow colorscheme on a vanilla Arch/Xmonad laptop. I cannot seem to get the proper (original) cursor line highlight back when I leave insert mode. I looked up the highlight color code in normal mode for afterglow and it corresponds to Gray84, which does not appear in the 256-color index. But I can do something like this
autocmd InsertLeave * highlight  CursorLine ctermbg=237 ctermfg=None

which gets it close, but does not respect the hue or transparency in the afterglow config. If I use the default color scheme, I can manually set the configuration without issue. But I want to use afterglow. I just want the original line highlight to appear when I leave insert mode.
On the other hand, if I use the default colorscheme, I can manually set these parameters without problem. In fact, this is what I have currently:

" colorscheme afterglow

set bg=dark
" transparent bg
" autocmd vimenter * hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE

" Enable CursorLine
set cursorline
" Default Colors for CursorLine
highlight CursorLine ctermbg=DarkGrey ctermfg=None

highlight Visual cterm=bold ctermbg=Cyan ctermfg=NONE

highlight CursorLine gui=underline cterm=underline 
highlight Visual cterm=bold ctermbg=Blue ctermfg=NONE

autocmd InsertEnter * highlight  CursorLine ctermbg=Red ctermfg=black

" Revert Color to default when leaving Insert Mode
autocmd InsertLeave * highlight  CursorLine ctermbg=DarkGray ctermfg=None

" Color of search hits
hi Search guibg=green guifg=wheat
hi Search cterm=NONE ctermfg=black ctermbg=green


I think we’re missing some significant details: by default cursorline doesn’t change appearance when you change modes.

@D.BenKnoble the snippet of code above does change the cursorline highlight to the shade of gray 237 when I exit insert mode back to normal mode. This happens for any colorscheme I use. If I do not include this loc, when I exit insert mode, the highlight of the insert mode (defined I presume, by the colorscheme) persists. What other details should I provide?

Ah, I see the issue: you didn't show the InsertEnter stuff before, which made this confusing.

Here's roughly how I would approach the problem:

Changing the highlight for Insert mode should stash away the old highlight for later
Restoring the highlight should use the saved highlight

Something like (~/.vim/plugin/insert-cursorline.vim)
if exists('g:loaded_insert_cursorline')
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_insert_cursorline = 1

augroup insert_cursorline
  autocmd InsertEnter * call s:insert_enter()
  autocmd InsertLeave * call s:insert_leave()
augroup end

function s:insert_enter() abort
  let s:saved = hlget('CursorLine')
  highlight CursorLine <your settings here>
endfunction

function s:insert_leave() abort
  call hlset(s:saved)
endfunction

This might need made more robust (detecting unset/empty s:saved, setting the 'force' attribute as needed, etc.). See the documentation for hlget()/hlset() for details.

Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. This code runs without error but has no effect. One problem I have is that when I use a given colorscheme say gruvbox, the default line highlight allows the fg text to peek through, whereas I cannot repeat this effect when leaving insert mode having set the bg and fg colors. I also cannot seem to set the colors of the search hits. I have this in my .vimrc after setting the colorscheme:
" Color of search hits
hi Search guibg=green guifg=wheat
hi Search cterm=NONE ctermfg=black ctermbg=green
with no effect. I am stumped.

Hm. I may be missing a pattern * in the autocommand.

This snippet from my .vimrc produces the effect I want. It was a matter of using autocmd properly:
colorscheme delek

set bg=dark



 " Enable CursorLine
set cursorline
    
    " " set cursor line highlight color normal mode
    autocmd vimenter * hi CursorLine ctermbg=8 ctermfg=NONE
    
    " " set cursor line highlight color in insert mode
    autocmd InsertEnter * highlight  CursorLine ctermbg=180 ctermfg=black
    
    " " Revert Color to default when leaving Insert Mode
    autocmd InsertLeave * highlight  CursorLine ctermbg=8 ctermfg=None 
    
    " " Color of search hits
    syntax on
    set hlsearch
    autocmd vimenter * hi Search ctermbg=gray
    autocmd vimenter * hi Search ctermfg=red
    autocmd vimenter * highlight Search guibg=purple guifg=NONE

Edit:following @Friedrich's suggestion, I finally have
" Enable CursorLine
set cursorline

" " transparent bg
" autocmd vimenter * hi CursorLine guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE

augroup enter
    autocmd!
" " set cursor line highlight color normal mode
     autocmd vimenter * hi CursorLine ctermbg=8 ctermfg=NONE

" " set cursor line highlight color in insert mode
     autocmd InsertEnter * highlight  CursorLine ctermbg=180 ctermfg=black

" " Revert Color to default when leaving Insert Mode
     autocmd InsertLeave * highlight  CursorLine ctermbg=8 ctermfg=None 
augroup END     

" " Color of search hits
syntax on
set hlsearch

augroup search
    autocmd!
    autocmd vimenter * hi Search ctermbg=gray
    autocmd vimenter * hi Search ctermfg=black
    autocmd vimenter * highlight Search guibg=purple guifg=NONE
augroup END

whereas before I just put autocomd! at the top of my vimrc.

Thanks for answering your own question. Unrelated: you should group your autocommands though. See  :help :augroup for the technique and rationale.

I added an edit to my OP. But what advantage does this have to simply putting autocmd! at the beginning of my vimrc?

Quoting from:help autocmd-remove: "Warning: You should normally not do this without a group, it breaks plugins, syntax highlighting, etc.". All of this is only a precaution in case you :source your vimrc manually, e.g. to try some changes.

Yes, I did read this but my (total noob) question is why? autocmd! at the beginning wil do exactly the same thing as automcd! in the gorups.

Having autocmd! globally in vimrc will: 1) delete all autocommands (there are none) 2) source autocommands in vimrc 3) proceed to source autocommands elsewhere in runtimepath. All of this is fine. Problem arises when you manually :source $MYVIMRC because step 1 will remove all global autocommands but step 3 won't be run -> autocommands from 3 will be lost. If you don't do that, it's fine.

@Friedrich Makes sense. Thanks.
